# XmlSerialization of array of classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a classes defined as below (generated using xsd):

```
[GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[SerializableAttribute]
[DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]
[DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRootAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
public class DataRequest
{
    private string _serviceField;
    private string _subscriptionField;

    public string Service
    {
        get
        {
            return _serviceField;
        }
        set
        {
            _serviceField = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("Subscription"), DefaultValue(null)]
    public string Subscription
    {
        get
        {
            return _subscriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            _subscriptionField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then , I define an array of the above class:

```
DataRequest[] requests = new DataRequest[2];
requests[0] = new DataRequest();
requests[1] = new DataRequest();
...
```

I want to serialize this array and end up with the below:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <DataRequest>
      <Service>ServiceA</DataService>
      <Subscription />
    </DataRequest>
    <DataRequest>
      <Service>ServiceB</DataService>
      <Subscription />
    </DataRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

However, when I call the below, where input is the array:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(input));
serializer.Serialize(writer, input);
```

I get the following:

```
  <Soap-ENV:Body>
    <ArrayOfDataRequest>
      <DataRequest>
        <Service>ServiceA</DataService>
        <Subscription />
      </DataRequest>
      <DataRequest>
        <Service>ServiceB</DataService>
        <Subscription />
      </DataRequest>
    </ArrayOfDataRequest>
  </Soap-ENV:Body>
```

Is there some way I can get rid of the **ArrayOfDataRequest** element, and just have the actual array elements serialized directly?

Comment: Hey Ben, I just tried it and I get the same thing (ArrayOfDataRequest).

Comment: I do the same thing with a complex class generated with the xsd.exe tool. I find the best option when serialising is to use List<DataRequest>, then to use the List.ToArray(); command to convert the List to an array. This avoids having to specify the size of the array you want to serialise.

Also you are able to specify options using `XmlWriterSettings XmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();` then `XmlSettings.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if i am wrong, but I think this is totally right what concerns SOAP-specific serialization. The immediate child of the body tag is the element for the parameter, in this case an array of DataRequest objects. When the serializer would leave out the ArrayOf... tags, the SOAP message would instead contain two parameters of type DataRequest.

Maybe you can specify why you would need such a "broken" message to find a solution for you actual problem?

Comment: Hey eFloh.  The service I am interacting with allows for such a broken SOAP request, where there is not a single, core root element.  I was hoping that there was some way I can modify the requests I send out to allow for the same but its looking like I will need to get the service changed to handle valid xml.

Comment: You may use a custom [MessageFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733844.aspx) to accomplish this when using WCF, there may be such a thing for classing asp.net web references, too.